# Unable to record in Jmeter using Mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: jmeter

While recording a https application from Jmeter by using Mozilla Firefox am getting a popup in the browser with title as 'This site is asking you to sign in.' with text box for username and password.

Not sure if we need to provide proxy - username/password (or) application - username/password here, tried both, but again and again getting the same popup and upon clicking on cancel in the popupp it shows 401-Unauthorised

Note:
Working fine from mozilla forefox when proxy is "Use system proxy settings". above issue exists only when proxy is "Manual Proxy Configuration" and recording from Jmeter.
Jmeter was lanched from cmd by providing proxy details.
jmeter certificate was installed in mozilla firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying username, password and your domain in *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
http.proxyUser=username
http.proxyPass=password
http.proxyDomain=your_domain
```

as it might be the case your corporate browser is configured to automatically login to the website using the account of the currently logged in user (the approach is known as [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on))

See [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) article for more information.

Also be aware of alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to bother about proxies and certificates as the extension is less "invasive" than JMeter's [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) proxy

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried to add below but still issue exists, also i cannot install Blazemeter in my system as its been restricted.                               
http.proxyUser=username
http.proxyPass=password
http.proxyDomain=your_domain

Comment: Did you really put `username` and `password` instead of your real domain credentials? I really like your approach to performance testing. As an alternative you can use your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to capture the requests, save them as [HAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) and convert the file into JMeter jmx script using [online conversion service](https://converter.blazemeter.com/)

Comment: i used the username and password of the proxy that was working fine for another Jmeter API test. in place of domain i specified the host of the application under test